# Evaluation Expression<Func<>> with variables

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

Our Company is having a Framework which requests Queries as Expression(Func(T, bool)) where T is the given Type ob the Buiniess Object.

I need to write an Provider for this and what to evaluate the Content of the Expression

If i have Queries like:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expr;
expr = (p) => p.Name == "Smith";
```

this is no Problem, then I can Use the Body Property of the Expression giving the following Result

```
Body = {(p.Name == "Smith")}
```

If i use Variables like this:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expr;
string nameToFind = "Smith";
expr = (p) => p.Name == name;
```

I get the following Result:

```
Body = {(p.Name == value(TestConsole.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).nameToFind)}
```

What I want is the have in this case the Variables Value in the parsed Expression like in the first example without variables.

Is ths possible?
I would be very greatful for an example or hint

Comment: You need to perform some bottomup analysis to determine what can/should be evaluated and then eval those Sub-expressions and replace them in the expression tree. In this case you basically would identity the display class/closure as a constant, evaluate it and replace it. https://github.com/mattwar/iqtoolkit/blob/master/src/IQToolkit/PartialEvaluator.cs is an example. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattwar/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i is a good (while old) series on the topic. I don't know enough to write an answer, but I've done this before, following the links

Comment: What is your `Expression` class? How do you access its `Body`?

Comment: The Class is from the dotnet Framework
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression ---
Body is a Property of the Expression Class, the Result is the output of the Expression.Body.ToString() funktion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is replace any `MemberExpression` that has a left hand side of type `ConstantExpression`, using reflection to get the value. This is what `ExpressionVisitor` is built for.

```cs
public class Simplify : ExpressionVisitor{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node){
        var expr = Visit(node.Expression);
        if (expr is ConstantExpression c){
            if (node.Member is PropertyInfo prop)
                return Expression.Constant(prop.GetValue(c.Value), prop.PropertyType);
            if (node.Member is FieldInfo field)
                return Expression.Constant(field.GetValue(c.Value), field.FieldType);
        }
        return node.Update(expr);
    }
}

expr = new Simplify().Visit(expr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is the exact solution to my Problem, great!